# en java eclipse debo calcular el premio de una persona de acuerdo a su edad

Tags: java, eclipse

este es el enunciado "Calcular el premio de una persona de acuerdo con su edad: Cuando la persona tiene entre 1 y 10 años le regalan un rompecabezas, cuando la persona tiene entre 10 y 15 año le regalan una ida a cine, cuando la persona tiene más de 15 años le regalan una ida a concierto en otro caso no hay regalo".

solo debo usar if y else, pero no se como aplicarlo correctamente

anexo el codigo:

```
package taller;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class premioedad {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    //Definicion de variables 
            int edad= 0;
            String premio = null;
            
            Scanner entrada =new Scanner(System.in);
            
            //peticion de datos 
            
            System.out.println("Digite edad");
            System.out.println("premio ropecabezas");
            System.out.println("premio ida a cine");
            System.out.println("premio ida a concierto");
            edad=entrada.nextInt();
            
            //proceso
            
             if (edad>=1){
                 System.out.println("premio rompecabezas");                }
             else 
                 if(edad<=10) {
                 System.out.println("premio ida a cine");
             }
             else 
                 if(edad>=15) {
                 System.out.println("premio ida a cine");
             }
             else if(edad<15) {
                 System.out.println("premio ida a concierto");
             }
             else  {
                    System.out.println("no hay premio");
                }
    
}

}
```

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu [primera medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 2):

```
if(edad >= 1 && edad <= 10)
{
     //Imprimo rompecabezas
}
else if (edad > 10 && edad <= 15)
{
     //Imprimo cine
}
else if(edad > 15)
{
     //Imprimo concierto
} 
else
{
     //Imprimo sin regalo
}
```

Lo que debes hacer es preguntar por los **rangos de edad** usando el **operador lógico && (and)**, lo cual quiere decir que si las dos condiciones de la condición se cumplen entonces se ejecuta el código dentro del **bloque if**.

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo haría tal que así:

```
        int edad= 0;
        String premio = null;
        
        Scanner entrada =new Scanner(System.in);
        
        //peticion de datos 
        
        System.out.println("Digite edad");
        edad=entrada.nextInt();
        
        //proceso
        
        if (edad>0 && edad<10)
        {
             System.out.println("Premio rompecabezas");                
        }
        else 
        {
            if (edad>=10 && edad<15)
            {
                System.out.println("premio ida a cine");
            }
            else
            {
                if(edad>=15)
                {
                    System.out.println("premio ida a concierto");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("no hay premio");
                }
            }
        }
```

Fijate que utilizo en el rango 1-15 un > 0 en vez de >=1, es lo mismo pero me parece mas simple el 0. Usando los operadores logicos AND && indicas que dos condiciones deben ser verdaderas para entrar en un if y procesar lo que ocurra dentro.